# PPI for iPhone 4S, 5, 5S, 6 and 6 plus

Tags: ios

When i tried calculating Pixels per inch for iPhone 4S, 5, 5S, 6 and 6 plus, I did not get exactly 326 PPI (for iPhone 6 and below) and 401 (for iPhone 6 plus), which is mentioned in most of the references.

My values are:

- iPhone 4S - 329.6 PPI
- iPhone 5 - 325.9 PPI
- iPhone 6 - 325.6 PPI
- iPhone 6 plus - 460.6 PPI

I have used the formula in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_density, also http://pixeldensitycalculator.com/

Also, I would like to be corrected if 2x and 3x images are not based on above pixels per inch value.

Highly appreciate if somebody can explain. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Everything you need to know about iOS device resolutions is at http://www.iosres.com/